# String to date in spark SQL (not dataframe)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use spark SQL to query a table where user-filled dates didn't follow any kind of strict formatting, so you see entries such as "10/4/21" and "10/04/21", for example.   My query attempt was

```
select CAST(unix_timestamp(thedate,"mm/d/yy") AS TIMESTAMP) from table
```

and this works for dates like "10/4/21", but not for "10/04/21" (and vice versa, the "mm/dd/yy" works for "10/04/21" but not for "10/4/21").  Is there any way to format the query so that it works for either date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting `thedate` using both formats and then apply a `COALESCE` such that the result from converting using valid format is returned.

```py
sql = """
SELECT thedate,
       Cast(COALESCE(unix_timestamp(thedate, "MM/d/yy"),
            unix_timestamp(thedate, "MM/dd/yy")
            ) AS TIMESTAMP) AS thedate_astimestamp 
FROM   (SELECT Explode(Array('10/4/21', '10/04/21', '10/11/21')) AS thedate)  
"""
spark.sql(sql).show()
```

### Output

```
+--------+-------------------+
| thedate|thedate_astimestamp|
+--------+-------------------+
| 10/4/21|2021-10-04 00:00:00|
|10/04/21|2021-10-04 00:00:00|
|10/11/21|2021-10-11 00:00:00|
+--------+-------------------+
```